I5-13500 (Raptor Lake) but Ubuntu 22.04 LTS detects Alder Lake
I have a problem, after installing Ubuntu and intel-gpu-tools, intel_gpu_top detects Intel gen12 Alderlake. This is not correct so I have trans-coding issues on this machine.

Generally the Linux distribution has to be newer than hardware, often 6 mo to a year to have latest kernel & drivers to support newest hardware. Have you tried 24.04.1?

Please fresh install (not upgrade to) 24.04.1. The upgrade path is buggy

Actually even the fresh install of my Ubuntu 24.04 was buggy coming right out of the gate, so the Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 is probably even buggier. Fortunately for every bug on my Ubuntu 24.04 I found that there was a way to fix it. It's noble of Canonical to include packages in the Ubuntu 24.04 default repositories that provide alternate ways of doing the same  thing.

I tried with new server, fresh install, still get the same problem I get the Alderlake, notice that I using Hetzner Dedicated Servers. @oldfred

Intel is pretty good about updating Linux kernel with new devices. Are  you sure system is not gen12, then? Example of updates to new kernel for future Intel versions: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.12-Perf

I verified my CPU is 13th Gen with lscpu.
